# Can't finish oracle 11g installation on Ubuntu 16.04 vbox - files not found

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, oracle11gr2

I have VirtualBox running on Windows 10 host and I created a Ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit) vm where I'm trying to install Oracle 11gR2 (32-bit) database but I can not finish the installation.

The issues I'm having are:

1) at the Prerequisites Check I have a message saying about the value for kernel parameter "semmni" being 0 while it should be 128 (I added such parameter to /etc/sysctl.conf but that was the thing to apparently because the message is still displayed); I check the 'Ignore All' in the wizard so I can move on but...

2) During the installation 'Link binaries' stage (under progress bar it says 'Linking dg4odbc Executables') the process is interrupted by message about a file being missing 'dbhome/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. I can click 'continue' but this only brings another message about another file being missing and that is '/dbhome/precomp/lib/ins_precomp.mk'. If I click 'continue' again I see the first message again.

I tried to google both files but no success - I still know nothing about how to deal with this. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle is not certified nor designed to work on Ubuntu.  Ubuntu is from an entirely different branch of the linux family tree.  People have published hacks to get it installed, but that is what they are -- hacks.  Even if you get it installed, every additional problem you face will be colored by that fact.  You need to create a vm with a *certified* version of Linux - Oracle, Red Had, Suse.  CentOS is not certified but from the same branch of Linux.  I'd just recommend Oracle Linux.  It's free and you know it is fully certified and compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is not certified or supported for Ubuntu. You need to use Red Hat, CentOS, or Oracle Linux.